# git log over restricts output when using --follow?

Tags: git, logging

On the following server:

```
gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> uname -a
Linux aragorn 2.6.31.12-0.2-default #1 SMP 2010-03-16 21:25:39 +0100 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> cat /etc/SuSE-release

openSUSE 11.2 (i586)
VERSION = 11.2
```

I use the following git:

```
gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> git --version

git version 1.7.2.2
```

I get (with a bash alias of `gitnp='git --no-pager'`):

(1)

```
gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> gitnp log --pretty=oneline junk.txt
500e8791578c5baf7a139d4997841769a995ac6b mod of junk and junk3
594ceed7a0fb35a860a6e2cb913d5398f09a861f 1st mod junk.txt
df271b2ebd5801bd8d827b0630577cad51c40896 initial junk.txt
```

(2)

```
gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> gitnp log --follow --pretty=oneline junk.txt
500e8791578c5baf7a139d4997841769a995ac6b mod of junk and junk3
594ceed7a0fb35a860a6e2cb913d5398f09a861f 1st mod junk.txt
df271b2ebd5801bd8d827b0630577cad51c40896 initial junk.txt
```

(3)

```
gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> gitnp log -2 --follow --pretty=oneline junk.txt
500e8791578c5baf7a139d4997841769a995ac6b mod of junk and junk3
```

(4)

```
gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> gitnp log -2 --pretty=oneline junk.txt
500e8791578c5baf7a139d4997841769a995ac6b mod of junk and junk3
594ceed7a0fb35a860a6e2cb913d5398f09a861f 1st mod junk.txt
```

Why don't I see 2 output lines for item (3) above?

-=> Gregg <=-

---

I upgraded to the latest and greatest, but still have the same problem:

> gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> git --version
>
> git version 1.7.2.3
>
> gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> gitnp log -2 --follow --pretty=oneline junk.txt
>   500e8791578c5baf7a139d4997841769a995ac6b mod of junk and junk3
>
> gsl@aragorn:~/gitTest> gitnp log --follow --pretty=oneline junk.txt
>   500e8791578c5baf7a139d4997841769a995ac6b mod of junk and junk3
>   594ceed7a0fb35a860a6e2cb913d5398f09a861f 1st mod junk.txt
>   df271b2ebd5801bd8d827b0630577cad51c40896 initial junk.txt

So is there another non-graphical reliable git way to obtain this information?

Comment: I'm closing this out as too localized. If you still need an answer for it, flag for mod attention.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [with git1.7.2.3](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.7.2.3.txt)?

> - "`git log --follow -M -p`" was seriously broken in 1.7.2, reporting
>     assertion failure.
> - Running "`git log`" with an incorrect option started pager nevertheless,
>     forcing the user to dismiss it.

I am not sure why the combination of '`--follow -2`' would limit the output to only one line.
It is however interesting to read [what Linux has to say when --follow was introduced](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2009/1/30/4856404/thread):

> `--follow` is a total hack, meant to just satisfy ex-SVN users who never knew anything about things like parenthood or nice revision graphs anyway.
>
> It's not totally fundamental, but the current implementation of "`--follow`" is really a quick preprocessing thing bolted onto the revision walking logic, rather than being anything really integral.
>
> It literally was designed as a "SVN noob" pleaser, not as a "real git functionality" thing.
>   The idea was that you'd get away from the (broken) mindset of thinking that renames matter in the big picture.

Comment: Ok, so it is probably not a completely reliable feature at this time. I see the gitk -- path1 path2 approach mentioned by Linus, but is there another non-graphical git way to walk the tree across renames?

Comment: @Gregg: none that comes into mind right now (except plumbing commands like `git rev-list`)